# Numerical differentiation (derivative) and downsampling

Tags: derivative, numerics, down-sample

I have some time course data which I would like obtain the first derivative of. As it seems quite difficult to model, I do not intend to fit a function to it, but rather compute the first derivative numerically (taking the difference of each measure from the one before via the [`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) function).

Now, I also want to down-sample my data to get rid of some noise. I have tried to calculate whether it makes a difference if I derive first and downscale that or downscale first and derive that. But however I try to look at it I can't seem to put the same variables on both sides of my equation (first side - how I believe differentiation and subsequent down-sampling work, and on the second side the converse).

$
\frac{(b-a)+(c-b)}{2} = \frac{c+d}{2}-\frac{b+a}{2}
$

Could you help me out determine whether it matters in what order I perform my operations?

Comment: Why do you think that downsampling would necessarily *reduce* noise? You might be interested in the small, delightful book R. W. Hamming (1989), *Digital Filters*, 3rd. ed., Prentice-Hall. It is a bit unconventional of a book on the topic, but has sections on the design and evaluation of differentiation filters that incorporate smoothing more directly and naturally.

Comment: I can graphically see on the time course that high-frequency, low-ampitude components which are irrelevant to my measurement disappear after I downsample. In any case, *assuming* that what I do makes sense, is there any "better" order in which to derive and downsample? and if so where's the difference?

Answer (score -1):

A quick and easy way to smooth any signal would be using a filter. For use with python, I'd recommend the scipy.signal.filtfilt function as it doesn't introduce any phase lag.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).